# Google Maps v3 - Why is LatLngBounds.contains returning false

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code in which I would expect the contains method to return true, but it returns false:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.38942944437183, -2.7379201682812226),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.69726685890506, -1.2456105979687226)
);

var center = bounds.getCenter();  // (55.04334815163844, -1.9917653831249726)

var x = bounds.contains(center);  // returns false
```

On the same page, where map is a reference to the Map object, the following code returns true as expected:

```
map.getBounds().contains(map.getBounds().getCenter())
```

Why might my call to `bounds.contains` be returning false?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Ah, brilliant. The `google.maps.LatLngBounds` constructor expects SouthWest and NorthEast `LatLng` parameters. I have somehow bungled up my coordinates and passed in NorthWest and SouthEast instead!

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.69726685890506,-2.7379201682812226),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.38942944437183, -1.2456105979687226)
);

var center = bounds.getCenter();  // still returns (55.04334815163844, -1.9917653831249726)

var x = bounds.contains(center);  // now returns true
```

Lesson learned: `getCenter` doesn't care if you created the `LatLngBounds` with NorthWest and SouthEast instead, but if you want `contains` to return a useful answer you better pass in the suggested SouthWest and NorthEast!

Comment: Thanks. Now that's a gotcha to look out for!

Answer (score 15):

I guess its easier to try this. It works for me without having to worry about NE orSW

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend({lat: 54.69726685890506, lng: -2.7379201682812226});
bounds.extend({lat: 55.38942944437183, lng: -1.2456105979687226});
var center = bounds.getCenter();  // still returns {lat: 55.04334815163844, lng: -1.9917653831249726}
var x = bounds.contains(center);  // now returns true
```

I know this post is old, but I came searching for answers here, so thought of updating from what I have learnt.

Comment: Yes, this is a much more productive and less confusing solution.

Comment: `bounds.extend` needs a LatLng object, not just numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that it worked for me:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(54.69726685890506,-2.7379201682812226);
bounds.extend(55.38942944437183, -1.2456105979687226); 
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but like Sharky said the coords must be a LatLng object, not just numbers. ie:
` myLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(54.69726685890506,-2.7379201682812226);
bounds.extend(myLatLang ); `