# Androids map - Check if center camera is within bounds

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to create a method to see if the center of the camera co-ords is within the bounds of an area, if so then do something.

When i try this i am getting error: `Operator ! cannot be applied to LatLngBounds`.

I have also tried `if(temp != new LatLngBounds(bounds1, bounds2))` but got the same error.

Here is my method

```
public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition)
        {
            LatLng temp = new LatLng(cameraPosition.target.latitude, cameraPosition.target.longitude);

            //Northwest corner of bounds
            LatLng bounds1 = new LatLng(-41.467668522, 173.03190229); 

            //Southwest corner of bounds 
            LatLng bounds2 = new LatLng(-40.095127348, 177.97574994);

            LatLngBounds outside = new LatLngBounds(bounds1, bounds2);

            //If the camera is within the bounds
            if(temp != outside)
            { 
               //do something
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Additionally, the google.maps.LatLngBounds constructor expects SouthWest and NorthEast LatLng parameters (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407524/1816603).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean northeast not northwest? Otherwise it would just be a line.

LatLngBounds has a [Contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng) method which allows for

```
if (outside.contains(temp){
    //do something
}
```

Outside is a bit of a misleading name for that variable though.