# Typescript interface with constructor - how to implement?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I am trying to use angular maps library that exposes below interface
https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/LatLng.html#source

```
export interface LatLng {
  constructor(lat: number, lng: number): void;
  lat(): number;
  lng(): number;
}
```

I need to construct an object of the same to use an API. **How can I implement this interface?**

Comment: Have you tried using export yourClassName Implements LatLng{}

Comment: You don't need to implement it, the implementation comes with the maps library.

Comment: I need to use an api (fitBounds) exposed from GoogleMapsAPIWrapper where I need to pass LatLngBounds. To do that I need to set all the points I want displayed on map in a bounds object which can be done using LatLngBounds.extends api which accepts a LatLng object only. There is no implementation provided which I can use to create this object in the library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code in this thread should suffice: [Google Maps v3 - Why is LatLngBounds.contains returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405539/google-maps-v3-why-is-latlngbounds-contains-returning-false), otherwise I don't understand what you're trying to do. I'm pretty sure that even if you do manage to create objects on your own that match this interface then you'll get runtime errors when those object will be used internally as your implementation will lack some inner info/logic.

Comment: I am using angular google maps library which exposes google map apis through a wrapper service [link](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/injectables/GoogleMapsAPIWrapper.html#source). I am not using google maps APIs directly and hence can't use the code mentioned in the other thread you pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library, but if you're sure that you need to instantiate such an object yourself then try something like:

```
function createLatLng(lat: number, lng: number): LatLng {
    return {
        lat: function() {
            return lat;
        },
        lng: function() {
            return lng;
        }
    } as LatLng;
}

let a = createLatLng(0, 0);
let b = createLatLng(10, -10);
```

The interface can't really be implemented without casting an object to `LatLng`, because of the `constructor` part, which should be part of the static declarations for the type.

Comment: Tried this but still not working :( . I get error "not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number"

Comment: Make sure that the `lat()` function indeed returns the number you passed to it, if that's the case then it probably does expect to get an instance of `LatLng` and you'll need to create it using the google maps lib

Answer (score -1):

why not create a component (or just a Class):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'SomeSpecific',
    styleUrls: ['./SomeSpecificComponent.component.css'],
    template: '<textarea>{{data?.text}}:{{data.value}}</textarea>'
})
export class SomeSpecificComponent implements LatLng {
   lat:number;
   lon:number
   constructor(lat: number, lng: number){
   }
   lat(){
      return lat;
   }
   lng()
      return lon;
   }
}
```

then using it like that:

```
new SomeSpecificComponent (0,0);
```