# getBounds().contains returning false

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want the marker to be detected and display a value that is assigned to a rectangle. Through research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405539/google-maps-v3-why-is-latlngbounds-contains-returning-false), but it is not applicable in my case as I only need a latlong point. I have found something similar to what I want and tried it out, which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343475/how-to-indicate-that-a-point-is-inside-the-circle-or-rectangle-by-geometry-libra)

But it does not seem to work in my case.
I have a rectangle below:

```
var rectangle1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35,
map: map,
bounds: {
  north: -37.822802,
  south: -37.822260,
  east: 145.036010,
  west: 145.035324
}
});
```

And I tried to insert a point, which is -37.822545, 145.035526, and this point is within the rectangle, and it is supposed to return true but it wasn't.
[Here is my JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyodanny/022xn1nq/3/)

Comment: Looks to me like that point is in the rectangle ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hh5er2xg/1/)), seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @Craicerjack but in the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLngBounds) it says that "Returns true if the given lat/lng is in this bounds.", which should detect the any latlong point that is within the rectangle, to what I understand.

Comment: @geocodezip that's what I'm hoping not the case since I need to figure this out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [`LatLngLiteralBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLngBoundsLiteral) input for [`google.maps.Rectangle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/polygon#Rectangle) is broken.  It creates a rectangle with north and south reversed.  With your original rectangle (`north: -37.822802, south: -37.822260`), I get:

```
NE1:-37.822802,145.03601  (north=-37.822802, incorrect)
SW1:-37.82226,145.035324  (south=-37.82226, incorrect)
```

Whereas if I create the rectangle with a [`google.maps.LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLngBounds) object, I get:

```
NE2:-37.82226,145.03601   (north=-37.82226, correct)
SW2:-37.822802,145.035324 (south=-37.822802, correct)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hh5er2xg/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

(blue markers are NE/SW of `rectangle2`, red markers are NE/SW of `rectangle1`.)

**someone should create an issue in the [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#issue-tracker)**

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 19,
    center: {
      lat: -37.82280243352756,
      lng: 145.0353240966797
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var rectangle1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: {
      north: -37.822802,
      south: -37.822260,
      east: 145.036010,
      west: 145.035324
    }
  });
  var rectangle2 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-37.822802, 145.035324), // SW
      new google.maps.LatLng(-37.822260, 145.036010)) // NE
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: -37.822545,
      lng: 145.035526
    },
    title: "-37.822545, 145.035526"

  });
  var NEmark1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: rectangle1.getBounds().getNorthEast(),
    title: "NE1:" + rectangle1.getBounds().getNorthEast().toUrlValue()
  });
  var SWmark1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: rectangle1.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
    title: "SW1:" + rectangle1.getBounds().getSouthWest().toUrlValue()
  });
  var NEmark2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: rectangle2.getBounds().getNorthEast(),
    title: "NE2:" + rectangle2.getBounds().getNorthEast().toUrlValue(),
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  });
  var SWmark2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: rectangle2.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
    title: "SW2:" + rectangle2.getBounds().getSouthWest().toUrlValue(),
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  });
  map.fitBounds(rectangle1.getBounds());
  console.log(rectangle1.getBounds().toUrlValue());

  console.log("NE1:" + rectangle1.getBounds().getNorthEast().toUrlValue());
  console.log("SW1:" + rectangle1.getBounds().getSouthWest().toUrlValue());
  document.getElementById('contains').innerHTML = "rectangle1 bounds.contains=" + rectangle1.getBounds().contains({
    lat: -37.822545,
    lng: 145.035526
  });
  console.log(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue());
  console.log(rectangle2.getBounds().toUrlValue());
  console.log("NE2:" + rectangle2.getBounds().getNorthEast().toUrlValue());
  console.log("SW2:" + rectangle2.getBounds().getSouthWest().toUrlValue());
  console.log(rectangle2.getBounds().contains({
    lat: -37.822545,
    lng: 145.035526
  }));
  document.getElementById('contains').innerHTML += " rectangle2 bounds.contains=" + rectangle2.getBounds().contains({
    lat: -37.822545,
    lng: 145.035526
  });
  console.log(rectangle2.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contains"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, this really helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mixed up your north and south parameters. (A larger negative latitude number is further south than a smaller one)

```
function initMap() {


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 19,
    center: {
      lat: -37.82280243352756,
      lng: 145.0353240966797
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var rectangle1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: {
      south: -37.822802,  // This is further south ...
      north: -37.822260,  // than this
      east: 145.036010,
      west: 145.035324
    }
  });
  alert(rectangle1.getBounds());
  alert(rectangle1.getBounds().contains({lat:-37.822545, lng:145.035526}));
}
```

With north and south switched like this, the js-fiddle returns true.

Comment: I thought as it remains creating the same shape, it should work, but yeah, this is a way to go, too. Thank you

Comment: I understand your train of thought, but technically a latitude range from e.g south: -37 to north: -38 , would wrap 359 degrees over both poles and around the opposite side of the earth.